# Swift string length strange behavior

Tags: swift

As a swift newbie, I find this behavior very odd. What's going on here?

```
"asdf".length  # 4 
var s = "asdf"
s.length # error: String does not have a member named length
```

I know you're supposed to use `count(s)` instead of `s.length` in swift 1.2. But why does `"asdf".length` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `"asdf"` literal is a `__NSCFString` instance. `NSString` does indeed have a `length` method.

```
"asdf".className
--> "__NSCFString"
```

Comment: what is className equivalent in swift 1.2?  I'm getting ```could not find member 'className'```

Comment: `className` is available in Swift 1.2, but only on `NSObject` subclasses.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that className is not available when I create iOS playground, but it is available when I create OSX playground

Comment: You're right, interesting. This seems to be the case in both Swift 1.2 and 2.0.

Comment: Technically, `"asdf"` is a *string literal*, which is its own thing in Swift. There are a variety of types that can be created from string literals (they conform the the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocol), so when you do something like this the compiler scans through the available types to try to figure out which one you meant. In this case, you end up with an `NSString`.